# Xcode 8 open new apple map

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

Need some help.This is my code below, when i click button GoMap, i was prompted this error
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
@IBAction func GoMap(_ sender: UIButton) {   
 UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=1 Republic Boulevard , Singapore 038975")! as URL)

}
```

Comment: Thanks guys both your answers works! by the way can i ask a question? how do i instantly show the direction route from my location to 1 Republic Boulevard , Singapore 038975

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is invalid. The spaces need to be escaped as %20:

```
URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=1%20Republic%20Boulevard,%20Singapore%20038975")!
```

Alternatively, use URLComponent + URLQueryItem to let the system escape it for you:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "http://maps.apple.com/maps")!
components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "saddr", value: "1 Republic Boulevard, Singapore 038975")]
let url = components.url!
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```